# Sampling Normal variables with linear constraints and given variances - Fraser (1951)

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to generate $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_d)$ such that $X_i \sim N(0, v_i)$  for $i = 1, \ldots, d$ satisfying the linear constraint $\sum_{j = 1}^dX_j = 0$.

The work of [Fraser (1951)](https://utstat.toronto.edu/dfraser/documents/5.pdf) proposes a solution to this problem. Although I was able to understand it, I was not able to implement it completely. My steps are below:

Steps:

1. Rewrite the linear constraint $\sum_{j = 1}^d X_j = 0$ as $\sum_{j = 1}^d b_{dj} X_j = 0$
   with $||\mathbf{b}_d||_2 = 1$ which yields:
   $$\mathbf{b}_d = [1/\sqrt{d}, \ldots, 1/\sqrt{d}].$$
2. Add d-1 rows to complete a matrix $\mathbf{B}_{d \times d}$ satisfying orthogonality conditions:
   $$<\mathbf{b}_k, \mathbf{b}_l> = 
   \begin{cases}
   0 \quad \mbox{if $k \neq l$} \\
    1 \quad \mbox{if $k = l$}.
   \end{cases}$$

Based on Gramm-Schmidt process, the $i^{th}$ row of $\mathbf{B}_{d \times d}$ - denoted as $\mathbf{b}_i$ -  is defined as
$$
b_{ij} \begin{cases}
0 \quad &\mbox{if $j < i$} \\ 
\left(\displaystyle\frac{d - i}{d - i + 1}\right)^{1/2} \quad& \mbox{if $i = j$} \\
- \displaystyle\frac{1}{[(d - i + 1)(d - i)]^{1/2}} \quad& \mbox{if $j > i$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Double-checking in R:

```
d <- 4

B <- matrix(NA, nrow = d, ncol = d)
B[d, ] <- rep((1/sqrt(d)), d)

for (i in 1:(d-1)){
  for (j in 1:d){
    if (j < i)
      B[i, j] <- 0
    if (i == j)
      B[i, j] <- ((d - i)/(d - i + 1))^(1/2)
    if (j > i)
      B[i, j] <- - 1/(((d - i + 1)*(d-i))^(1/2))
  }
}

# Normalized
k <- 1
l <- 1
B[k, ] %*% B[l, ]
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1

# Orthogonal
k <- 1
l <- 2
B[k, ] %*% B[l, ]
#              [,1]
#[1,] -3.469447e-18
```

The matrix $\mathbf{B}$ can be considered as an orthogonal rotation of $n$-space. Consider coordinates $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ with respect to the new axes:

$$Y_i = \sum_{j = 1}^d b_{ij} X_j.$$

In a matrix notation, $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}$. A set of constrained variables $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is transformed to a set of unconstrainted variables $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1}, Y_n = 0)$.

Double-checking in R:

```
X <- c(1, 2, 3, -6)
Y <- B%*%X
Y
#         [,1]
#[1,] 1.154701
#[2,] 2.857738
#[3,] 6.363961
#[4,] 0.000000
```

3. Establish variances of the variables $\mathbf{Y}$ based on the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$. Given that $\mathbf{X} \sim N_d(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{V})$ with $\mathbf{V} = diag(v_1, \ldots, v_d)$, it follows that

$$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{B}_{(d-1)\times(d-1)}\mathbf{X} \sim N_{d-1}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\tau}),$$
where $\boldsymbol{\tau}_{(d-1)\times(d-1)} = \mathbf{B}_{(d-1)\times d}\mathbf{V}_{d\times d)}\mathbf{B}_{(d-1)\times d}^T$ with $\mathbf{A}_{l\times k}$ is a sub matrix with the first $l$ rows and $k$ columns of $\mathbf{A}$.

In our running example assuming that $v_i = 1 \forall i$ for simplicity,

```
V <- diag(1, nrow = d, ncol = d)
tau <- B[1:(d-1), ]%*%V%*%t(B[1:(d-1), ])
> tau
#              [,1]         [,2]          [,3]
#[1,]  1.000000e+00 2.775558e-17 -2.775558e-17
#[2,]  2.775558e-17 1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[3,] -2.775558e-17 0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
```

4. Generate $\mathbf{Y}$ as described in step 4. Then, calculate $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{Y}$ because $\mathbf{B}$ is an orthonormal matrix.

```
set.seed(1234)
aux <- matrix(rnorm((d-1)*100000,0,1),100000,d-1)
y <- cbind(aux%*%chol(tau), 0)

x <- y %*%B
```

However, this procedure does not produce the desirable variances:

```
mean(rowSums(x))
# [1] -9.463654e-19
apply(x, 2, var)
# [1] 0.7491879 0.7423549 0.7546185 0.7540128
```

I think that my error is probably at step 3 since the equality $\tau_{ii} = v_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, d$ always will hold because $\mathbf{B}$ is an orthonormal matrix. However, my intuition is that $\tau_{ii}$ should be higher than $v_i$. I could not grasp very well the discussion in Fraser's section 4 summarized as steps 5.3 and 5.4 in section 5.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your mistake is in $\tau$, you cannot use the normality assumption to state that $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{B}^{\prime}$.  I will write a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $(Y_1, \cdots, Y_{n-1}) \sim N_{n-1}\left(\boldsymbol{0}_{n-1}, \boldsymbol{T}\right)$.  For simplicity, let $v_i=1$ for all $i$ and let $b_i^{\ast}$ denote the $i$th column of $\boldsymbol{B}$ excluding observation $b_{ni}$.  That reference states that the elements of $\boldsymbol{T} = (\tau_{rs})$ are found by solving the set of $n$ equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\sum_{s=1}^{n-1} b_{ri}\tau_{rs}b_{si} = 1 \quad \mbox{for} \quad i=1,\cdots,n.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that this can be expressed as the equivalent quadratic form $\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\boldsymbol{T}b_i^{\ast}=1.$

Now we wish to solve for the elements of $\boldsymbol{T}$.  Since the quadratic form is a scalar, it is equal to its trace.  Using the fact that $\mbox{tr}(AB)=vec^{\prime}(A^{\prime})vec(B)$, $\mbox{tr}(AB)=\mbox{tr}(BA)$, and for a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, $A$, that $D_n vech(A)=vec(A)$, with $vec(\cdot)$ denoting the vectorization of a matrix, $vech(\cdot)$ denoting the half-vectorization of a matrix and $D_n$ denoting the duplication matrix of order $n$.  Since $vech(\boldsymbol{T})$ contains all of the unique elements of $\boldsymbol{T}$, we can create a linear system of equations using the equivalent formulation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\boldsymbol{T}b_i^{\ast} &=& \mbox{tr} \left(\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\boldsymbol{T}b_i^{\ast}\right) \\ 
&=& \mbox{tr} \left(b_i^{\ast}\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\boldsymbol{T}\right) \\
&=& vec^{\prime}\left(b_i^{\ast}\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\right)vec\left(\boldsymbol{T}\right) \\
&=& vec^{\prime}\left(b_i^{\ast}\left(b_i^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\right) \boldsymbol{D}_{n-1} vech\left(\boldsymbol{T}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Next let
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{W} = \begin{pmatrix}
vec^{\prime}\left(b_1^{\ast}\left(b_1^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\right) \boldsymbol{D}_{n-1} \\
\vdots \\
vec^{\prime}\left(b_n^{\ast}\left(b_n^{\ast}\right)^{\prime}\right) \boldsymbol{D}_{n-1}. 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence the original $n$ set of equations can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{W} vech\left(\boldsymbol{T}\right) = \boldsymbol{1}_n,
\end{eqnarray*}
and for any generalized inverse of $\boldsymbol{W}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{W}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
vech\left(\boldsymbol{T}\right) = \left(\boldsymbol{W}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{W}\right)^{-} \boldsymbol{W}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{1}_n
\end{eqnarray*}.

In fact, for this problem, one may reduce the above to find that $\boldsymbol{T} = \frac{n}{n-1} \boldsymbol{I}_{n-1}$.

Using the ${\tt matrixcalc}$ package in ${\tt R}$ to obtain the duplication matrix, the correct code should be

````
d <- 4

B <- matrix(NA, nrow = d, ncol = d)
B[d, ] <- rep((1/sqrt(d)), d)

for (j in 1:(d-1)){
  for (i in 1:d){
    if (i < j)
      B[j, i] <- 0
    if (i == j)
      B[j, i] <- ((d - j)/(d - j + 1))^(1/2)
    if (i > j)
      B[j, i] <- - 1/(((d-j+1)*(d-j))^(1/2))
  }
}

set.seed(1234)
library(matrixcalc)
library(Matrix)
library(MASS)
D = duplication.matrix(d-1)
W = matrix(0,d,d*(d-1)/2)
for (i in 1:d){
    W[i,] = t(as.vector(B[-d,i]%*%t(B[-d,i])))%*%D
}
vech.tau = as.vector(ginv(t(W)%*%W)%*%t(W)%*%rep(1,d))
tau = matrix(0,d-1,d-1)
l=1
for(i in 1:(d-1)){
    for (j in i:(d-1)){
        tau[i,j] = vech.tau[l]
        l = l+1
    }
}
tau = forceSymmetric(tau)
aux <- matrix(rnorm((d-1)*100000,0,1),100000,d-1)
sqrt_tau <- chol(tau)
y <- cbind(aux%*%chol(tau), 0)

x <- y %*%B
mean(rowSums(x))
# [1] -6.543378e-19
apply(x, 2, var)
# [1] 0.9989172 0.9898065 1.0061580 1.0053505
```
````